# What exactly A[:, state] means in the python?

Tags: python, numpy

What exactly this the following line means?

```py
# p=T[:, state] what does this means?

# Here is the complete code
import numpy as np

T = np.array([ [ 0.40, 0.56, 0.03, 0.01],
               [0.45, 0.51, 0.04, 0.00],
               [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25 ],
               [0.00, 0.00, 0.01, 0.99 ]])

xk = np.arange(len(T))

def gen_sample(state):
    return np.random.choice(xk, 1, p=T[:, state])
```

I understand it takes the transition matrix but what does " : " and "state" mean?

Comment: Did you check the numpy documentation?

Comment: `state` is a variable passed into the function

Comment: It means `A.__getitem__(slice(None), state)`. What *that* means depends on how `A.__getitem__` is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` is a numpy array:

```
In [38]: T
Out[38]: 
array([[0.4 , 0.56, 0.03, 0.01],
       [0.45, 0.51, 0.04, 0.  ],
       [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.01, 0.99]])
```

`T[..]` is indexing; in this case is selects a column of the array:

```
In [39]: T[:,0]
Out[39]: array([0.4 , 0.45, 0.25, 0.  ])
In [40]: T[:,3]
Out[40]: array([0.01, 0.  , 0.25, 0.99])
```

Spend some time to read the `numpy` basics.  Indexing an array is a very basic operation.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `:` means all "row"s in this matrix are selected and `state` is the "column" index param.

Has many possibles to access an array, and `[start:end]` is by slicing.

Consider:

`a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])`

if you try `a[1:4]` it's return a slice of `a` starting at second position ending at fifth (remember that python indexes starts on zero)

By default, if you not pass a start and/or end position, they use 0 to start and `len(a)` to end.

Learn mor about on this [w3schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_slicing.asp)